# How to force the new 10.10.3 Photo app to open in full screen after restart?

Tags: fullscreen, photos.app

Every time I start my new photo app, it NEVER starts in full-screen.
Even if its was previously closed in full-screen!

Comment: same for me...bug?

Comment: Do other apps resume with their window state? Is it just Photos.app?

Comment: Yes, I have the same with Firefox. And a bit different with Acrobat Pro as it doesn't start at all after a system restart (but if manually started, it starts in full-screen!)

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > General > Uncheck "Close windows when quitting an application".